# How do I insert a post with custom post type and relate it to a custom taxonomy?

Tags: posts, customization, taxonomy, wp-insert-post

I'm trying to figure out how to insert a new post. I have a custom post-type (course) that is related to a custom taxonomy (categorycourses).

I've managed to insert a post with custom post type course, **but I can't figure out how to relate this post to custom taxonomy categorycourses**.

```
//This will return array of category-courses (temporarily tables kurser and kategorier created by me)
$courses = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT * FROM `kurser` kur
LEFT JOIN kategorier kat ON (kat.id = kur.kategori)" );

//Go through category-courses and put them into wordpress-tables
foreach($courses as $course) {
    $name = $course->kursnamn;   
    //If name has length
    if (strlen($name)>0) {              
        $new_post = array(
            'post_title' => $name,
            'post_content' => '',
            'post_status' => 'publish',
            'post_date' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
            'post_author' => $user_ID,
            'post_type' => 'course'
        );

        //This works because an ID is returned                
        $post_id = wp_insert_post($new_post); 

        $current_term_category = 33;         
        if (substr($name, 0, 3) == 'lid') {
            $cat_city = 29;
        }
        else {
            $cat_city = 30;                
        }
        $cat_ids = array($current_term_category, $cat_city);

        //term_id 30,29 and 33 exists in wp_terms-table
        //This is where I've done something wrong.    
        wp_set_object_terms( $post_id, $cat_ids, 'categorycourses', false);
    }

}
```

The custom types courses are inserted but no relations to any categorycourses ((29 or 30) and 33) are made. **What am I doing wrong?**

Comment: you made `$cats_ids` an array, and then you put that array into another array.

Comment: @Milo, good spotted! Unfortunately it didn't help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll supply with an answer so people with the same issue in the future might be helped...

***The problem wasn't in the actual function. It was about when the taxonomy (categorycourses) was registered...***

Function for registerering custom post type course and course-category:

```
function courses_with_cats() {

    //Register custom post type for courses
    $course_labels = array(
      'name' => 'Kurser',
      'singular_name' => 'Kurs',
      'add_new' => 'Lägg till',
      'add_new_item' => 'Lägg till ny kurs',
      'edit_item' => 'Redigera kurs',
      'new_item' => 'Ny kurs',
      'all_items' => 'Alla kurser',
      'view_item' => 'Visa kurs',
      'search_items' => 'Sök kurser',
      'not_found' => 'Inga kurser funna',
      'not_found_in_trash' => 'Inga kurser funna i sopkorgen',
      'parent_item_colon'  => '',
      'menu_name' => 'Kurser'
    );
    $course_args = array(
      'labels' => $course_labels,
      'public' => true,
      'publicly_queryable' => true,
      'show_ui' => true,
      'show_in_menu' => true,
      'query_var' => true,
      'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'kurs' ),
      'capability_type' => 'post',
      'has_archive' => 'kurser',
      'hierarchical' => false,
      'menu_position' => null,
      'supports' => array('title','editor','author','comments'),      
    );
    register_post_type( 'course', $course_args );


    //Register custom taxonomy for courses-categories
    $course_cat_labels = array(
      'name' => 'Kurskategori',
      'singular_name' => 'Kurskategori',
      'search_items' => 'Sök kategori',
      'all_items' => 'Alla kategori',
      'parent_item' => 'Föräldrakategori',
      'parent_item_colon' => 'Föräldrakategori:',
      'edit_item' => 'Redigera kategori',
      'update_item' => 'Uppdatera kategori',
      'add_new_item' => 'Lägg till ny kategori',
      'new_item_name' => 'Namn på ny kategori',
      'menu_name' => 'Kurskategori'     
    );
    $course_cat_args = array(
      'hierarchical' => true,
      'labels' => $labels,
      'show_ui' => true,
      'show_admin_column' => true,
      'query_var' => true,
      'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'kurser/kategori')
    );

    register_taxonomy( 'categorycourses', array('course'), $course_cat_args );
}
```

**BEFORE:** (This did NOT work)

```
add_action('init', 'convertaddcoursesfromaccess');

//Hooks for courses and courses-categories
add_action( 'init', 'courses_with_cats' );
```

**AFTER:** (This did work!)

```
//Hooks for courses and courses-categories
add_action( 'init', 'courses_with_cats' );

add_action('init', 'convertaddcoursesfromaccess');
```

(NOTE!!! In first case it worked to insert a custom post type (course) even if the post-type wasn't registered. But it was not possible relate the post with a custom taxonomy with `wp_set_object_terms()`)

Thanks to Rahil Wazir that made me aware that WP functions `wp_set_object_terms()` and `wp_set_post_terms()` both works with custom post types **EVEN** if Wordpress Codex states otherwise in http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_set_post_terms :

> "This function will only work on the native post type. For a taxonomy
>   on a custom post type use wp_set_object_terms()"

I've confirmed that this is NOT the case, both worked functions above worked for me with custom post type (course). But I use `wp_set_object_terms()` because my suspicion is that WP will make `wp_set_post_terms()` deprecated in the future (this is just a qualified guess though)

Comment: Glad you have figure it out yourself.

Comment: @RahilWazir - without your answer and comments I wouldn't manage to figure it out! :-)

Comment: The real question here would be, what is `convertaddcoursesfromaccess` doing? Otherwise it makes no sense that just reordering the `add_action()`-parts solved your problem.

Comment: True! I should supplied more code initially.

Answer (score 2):

Try changing this line

```
  wp_set_object_terms( $post_id, array($cat_ids), 'categorycourses', false);
```

to

```
  wp_set_object_terms( $post_id, $cat_ids, 'categorycourses', false);
```

`$cat_ids` is already an array and you are writing with in array again.
Hope it helps.

Comment: Good spotted, but unfortunately the change didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing `wp_set_object_terms` with `wp_set_post_terms`

```
// Set Categories For Current Post
wp_set_post_terms($post_id, array(29, 30, 33), 'categorycourses'); //Change array(29, 30, 33) with your $cat_ids
```

I don't know why your `wp_set_object_terms` not working but `wp_set_post_terms` should work.

**Edited:**

From [wp codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_set_object_terms):

Perhaps the wp_set_post_terms() is a more useful function, since it checks the values​​, converting taxonomies separated by commas and validating hierarchical terms in integers.

Comment: Yes, but the documentation also says... "This function will only work on the native post type. For a taxonomy on a custom post type use wp_set_object_terms()"

Comment: No way! I have used the same above method for my custom post type of custom taxonomy. have you tried it?

Comment: It's true. The documentation say so, but the documentation might be incorrect. I will try it and come back to you! Thanks for your suggestion! :-)

Comment: Haha it might be incorrect YES!!!, i also read it just now.

Comment: *hehe* Actually they both seem to work in the same way. I've traced the return value to this: WP_Error Object ( [errors] => Array ( [invalid_taxonomy] => Array ( [0] => Ogiltig taxonomi ) ) [error_data] => Array ( ) ), so now I'm able to figure what's going on...

Comment: have you checked by passing `array(29, 30, 33)` these manually?

Comment: yes, I tried your exact code. I think it has something to do when!? the taxonomy is registered. If I'm not thinking incorrectly, I recall that it was possible to change priority of the init-functions.

Comment: Invalid taxonomy means your taxonomy is not matching the current one you are passing to the `wp_set_post_terms` or `wp_set_object_terms`

Comment: My thought that it wasn't registered at the time was correct. I will answer myself - I will describe it more in an answer that I'll give myself - so someone else with the same issue might be helped in the future.

Comment: I've answered myself now :-)